# I would like to highlight values in a displayed pdf based off a users input. The project is currently written using vueJs. Anyone have any resources?

Tags: pdf

The project is currently written in vueJs 3 using the composition API.
I have an input field and a pdf displayed using the iframe HTML tag.
I want to have the ability to type a word in the input field and all occurrences of the input word highlight on the pdf document.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I would achieve this or resources that may help?

I've tried a few javascript packages but cannot seem to get them to work, they're likely outdated as I found these using ChatGPT which I believe only has access to data pre Oct 2021.